# create regex expression for url

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, frontend, web-frontend

I will have urls as either

```
http://www.yellowpages.com/randolph-nj/mip/brookside-village-apartments-1041662
```

or

```
http://www.yellowpages.com/randolph-nj/mip/brookside-village-apartments-1041662?from=pubapi_5k2t9
```

What is the best/most efficient regex expression I can make to match these.  Basically,  It's going to be a url fitting

`/^https?:\/\/www.yellowpages.com\/[\w|-]+\/mip\/[\w|-]+-\d+/`

then sometimes a question mark or not followed by `from=`  text I made up

Comment: Please don't rush in posting. Be more compassionate about us, readers.

Comment: I'm wondering how to make it either or i.e. ?from or not using that

Comment: Try making the from part optional `(?:\?from=[^&]+)? ` and escape the dots `\.` if you want to match them literally:  [`^https?:\/\/www\.yellowpages\.com\/[\w|-]+\/mip\/[\w|-]+-\d+(?:\?from=[^&]+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/zd6o0r/1)

Comment: can be done either using `?` quantifier or alternation with empty

Comment: So you want to extract a URL out of a string in the format "URLfrom=someemail"? Why not `.*(?=from=)` ?

Comment: @zᴉɹɥƆ it can be a string, number, or _ symbol after from=

Comment: @Thefourthbird your example seems to match everything even if it just has fro= instead of from=

Comment: This is an updated example which matches not a `\n` or an ampersand `&`  instead of only not an ampersand [`^https?:\/\/www\.yellowpages\.com\/[\w|-]+\/mip\/[\w|-]+-\d+(?:\?from=[^&\n]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/zd6o0r/3)

Answer (score 0):

Might this be what you're looking for?

```
/^https?:\/\/www.yellowpages.com\/[\w|-]+\/mip\/[\w|-]+-\d+(\?from=pubapi_[^\s]{5})?/
```

The above regex will match the base url and optionally match `?from=pubapi_` plus five non-space characters.

> I'm wondering how to make it either or i.e. ?from or not using that

That must be the essence of your question I assume. This can be achieved by creating an optional group, using `()?` (note the **?** at the end which means 'zero or one of'). I would suggest playing around on https://regex101.com/ to get a feel for such 'advanced' regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your regex you could escape the dots `\.` if you want to match them literally.

If you want to match an optional querystring parameter you could use an optional `?` non capturing group `(?:` and assert the end of the string `$`

Some of the ways you could match the querystring parameter:

- `(?:\?from=\w+)?` to match one or more wordcharacters `\w+` (that will match `pubapi_5k2t9`)
- `(?:\?from=pubapi_\w{5})?` Match exactly 5 wordcharacters after pubapi_
- `(?:\?from=[^&]+)?$` Match not an ampersand using a negated character class (or extend the character class with `\n` to not match a newline)

An example for the first option:

[`^https?:\/\/www\.yellowpages\.com\/[\w|-]+\/mip\/[\w|-]+-\d+(?:\?from=\w+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/pF5aVg/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "http://www.yellowpages.com/randolph-nj/mip/brookside-village-apartments-1041662",
  "http://www.yellowpages.com/randolph-nj/mip/brookside-village-apartments-1041662?from=pubapi_5k2t9",
  "http://www.yellowpages.com/randolph-nj/mip/brookside-village-apartments-1041662?fro=pubapi_5k2t9"
];
let pattern = /^https?:\/\/www\.yellowpages\.com\/[\w|-]+\/mip\/[\w|-]+-\d+(?:\?from=\w+)?$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```